# Angle between two lines is not always working

Tags: python

I am calcualting the angle between two lines on the following image
[image]

with this code

```
# the lines are in the format (x1, y1, x2, y2)
def getAngle(line_1, line_2):
    angle1 = math.atan2(line_1[1] - line_1[3], line_1[0] - line_1[2])
    angle2 = math.atan2(line_2[1] - line_2[3], line_2[0] - line_2[2])

    result = math.degrees(abs(angle1 - angle2))
    if result < 0:
        result += 360

    return result
```

Now the function works between the two red lines (almost on top of each other) and the red and the green line. However, between the red and the blue line the fuction returns 239.1083 when it should be ~300. Since it is working in some of the cases and not others i am not sure what the problem is.

Some example inputs and outputs:

```
getAngle((316,309,316,-91), (316,309,421,209)) = 46.3971 # working
getAngle((316,309,316,-91), (199,239,316,309)) = 239.108 # should be around 300
```

Comment: Could you please give us some sample inputs, expected answer and the answer which you're getting?

Comment: @LazyCoder working example getAngle((316,309,316,-91), (316,309,421,209)) = 46.3971, none working example getAngle((316,309,316,-91), (199,239,316,309)) = 239.108 when it should be around 300

Comment: @chris so subtract the image height from the y coords of all the lines?

Comment: it really depends how you defined coordinates here, I'm confused now by your -91 you are passing in. typically x and y are the other way round to cartesian and the y/vertical one needs to be inverted

Comment: @chris, ah thats the large vertical line. When i was creating it i just subtracted a number from the coords of the centre to create it. It does not seem to be a problem tho as i just changed it to a lower value so that it is positive and its seems to still give the same results.

Comment: try the lines defined in normal cartesian (5,10, 5, 5) (middle),  (7.5,7.5, 5, 5) (right) and  (2.5,7.5, 5, 5) (left). they both give 45 degrees like they should, how tall is the image?

Comment: @chris its 640 pixels high

Comment: @chris, still the same incorrect result with the normal cartesian coords

Comment: @Sean did my answer below was of any use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example getAngle((316,309,316,-91), (199,239,316,309)), The culprit is measurement of angles in this case.

Angles are getting calculated w.r.t. positive X axis. The angle which you have defined here, calculates phi in the given image below rather than theta, which you should be expecting. Since the rotation is negative in nature (observe the arrow for phi), any subsequent calculation must ensure positive rotation, rather than the negative one. Otherwise, you'll be short by the complementary angle, roughly.

In the given example, the correct angle of line2 should be about +210 degrees, or about -150 degrees. Similarly, the angle of line1 could be +90 or -90 degrees. Now, it's all in the game of which ones to add or subtract and how?

- The 239.something, let's call it 240 is gotten by abs(90-(-150)) The
- 300 you are expecting is gotten by abs(-90 - (+210)).

The difference of 60 degrees is the complement of theta = 30 degrees.

So, it's not so much as bad formula, it's bad argument passing and checking to get positive or negative angles.

[image: Image2]
[image: Image1]

Comment: @Sean Did this help?

Comment: Yes thanks, i suspected it was something like this. The 2nd image cleared up the solution.